# Grant SD card write access

Tags: android, apk, android-manifest, android-4.4-kitkat

How can I grant SD card write access on downloaded apps by editing AndroidManifest.xml? I heard that some file managers like ES file manager has access to SD card write. I tried to add WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, but not working. (I use KitKat)

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to write to the SD card?

Comment: Not my app, just trying to install Galaxy Note 2(II)'s My File app to Galaxy S4 mini KitKat because Note 2's file manager app has a feature I like, and I am editing the app only for me. It installed but it fails to modify contents of SD card

Comment: What do you mean "editing the app"?

Comment: The app's APK file's manifest XML using APK editor

Comment: APK's are signed by the developer. In this case, Samsung. If you edit an APK you would need to sign it with your own signing key. You are not Samsung. On a Samsung device, any apps signed by Samsung have special privileges (like access to all files on the SD card). Since you are not Samsung, your "edited" app does not have access. Sorry.